# 401 unauthorized spring boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, resttemplate

I wrote a test and I expect to get 401, but I get an exception.
when I run a test on debugging mode, I saw 401 status is handled in HttpUrlConnection.class (please find it below) and I get an exception with a response
I would like to know how can I fix this and pass the test?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserAuthenticationTest {

    @Test
    public void unAuthenticatedRequestTest() {
        String url = "/user/favorite/add/{marketId}";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Map<String, String> urlParams = new HashMap<>();
        urlParams.put("marketId", "1");

        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
                .buildAndExpand(urlParams)
                .toUri();
        uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUri(uri)
                .queryParam("favoriteName", "something")
                .build()
                .toUri();

        ResponseEntity<Favorite> favoriteResponseEntity = testRestTemplate.exchange(
                uri, HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(headers), Favorite.class);

        Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, favoriteResponseEntity.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

HttpUrlConnection.class

```
      if (respCode == 401) {
                            if (this.streaming()) {
                                this.disconnectInternal();
                                throw new HttpRetryException("cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode", 401);
                            }
```

and this is the error I get when I run the test:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:36725/user/favorite/add/1": cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode; nested exception is java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, 401 status is set from servlet filter so it never returns ResponseEntity of Favorite.class, but it returns ResponseEntity of Void.class.
So when expecting ResponseEntity of Favorite.class, it retries access to the resource and can't, so it throws  ResourceAccessException.